# Writing to file with existing line breaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, line-breaks

I have a variable which contains line breaks such as \r and \r\n. I want to write the text **with** these line breaks to a file.

I've tried this, when using console.log(content) it seems like it is working, however when I take a look at the file it has written to, it displays this: `test1\ntest2\r\ntest3` - making it obvious that this approach does not work.

Code:

```
    var content = args.content;

    var content = content.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, os.EOL);

        fs.writeFile(args.path, content, function(error) {

            callback(error);

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent().` this function encodes a URI component.encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters: `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`

```
content = encodeURIComponent(content);
```

Comment: Solved it, thanks. Was literally tearing my hear out.